# Juypter Notebook does not navigavte through folders/files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am at my freaking end with this. I don't know what has changed but with Jupyter Notebooks 6.0.3 it takes forever to start. Once I finally have a notebook open, when I launch a new note book I just get a blank page or when I try to navigate through the folders nothing happens.

When I click on the folder, the file path at the top shows the selected to folder, but I just stay on the current page.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, using the conda prompt to run `conda update --all`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My simple advice: dump the Conda.  You do not need Conda or Anaconda for Python, Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter Lab.  Many of the Jupyter questions here at Stack involve newbies having trouble with Anaconda & Conda.  And most often the only answer is to reinstall this or that.  People want some Wizard of Oz software (Anaconda) to magically manage all their software.    But the problem isn't the software - python / Jupyter, etc. The problems are most often caused by the Wizard of Oz.  Do yourself a favor and learn how to install software, updates, and packages yourself.  You won't be disappointed.

Comment: I appreciate the advice but this is not helping me at all.